# Unable to build Sphinx autodocs on read the docs

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc

I know the question has been asked before, but the proposed solutions still do not work for me. When I build my docs online I am getting these warnings:

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'Models.CommunityModel' from module 'dcFBA'; the following exception was raised:
> No module named 'dcFBA'
> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'DynamicModels.DynamicModelBase' from module 'dcFBA'; the following exception was raised:
> No module named 'dcFBA'

I know it has something to do with the folder structure and conf.py file, but I tried everything now. So I would be really grateful for the help.

This is my rst file containing the code:

```
10. API
===================


CommunityModel
---------------------------------

.. automodule:: dcFBA.Models.CommunityModel
   :members:
   :show-inheritance:

DynamicModelBase
-------------------------------

.. automodule:: dcFBA.DynamicModels.DynamicModelBase
   :members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

My .readthedocs.yaml:

```
# .readthedocs.yaml
# Read the Docs configuration file
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config-file/v2.html for details

# Required
version: 2

# Set the OS, Python version and other tools you might need
build:
  os: ubuntu-22.04
  tools:
    python: "3.10"
   
# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF and ePub
# formats:
#    - pdf
#    - epub

# Optional but recommended, declare the Python requirements required
# to build your documentation
# See https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/reproducible-builds.html`

python:
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
    # Install our python package before building the docs
   #  - method: pip 
   #    path: .


sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py
  fail_on_warning: true
```

I already tried uncommenting the -method pip, but that did not seem to do the trick.

My docs/conf.py

```
# Configuration file for the Sphinx documentation builder.
#
# For the full list of built-in configuration values, see the documentation:
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html

# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#project-information

import sys
import os


# sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
# print(sys.path)

import pkg_resources

installed_packages = pkg_resources.working_set
installed_packages_list = sorted(
    ["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version) for i in installed_packages]
)
    print(installed_packages_list)
```

I've tried to build it with:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("."))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../"))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("../../"))
```

I know the package is getting installed properly as with the pkg_resources I print all the package names that are installed and dcfba is one of the listed packages.

I install the package in the docs/requirements.txt file with this line:

```
cbmpy==0.8.4 #TODO fix this before publishing
cplex==22.1.1.0
docutils==0.18.1
sphinx==6.2.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==1.2.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jquery==4.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==1.1.5
sphinxcontrib-napoleon
pyparsing==3.1
-e .
```

Finally this is the folder structure of my package:

```
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── SystemsBiologyLab.md
├── dcFBA
│   ├── DefaultModels.py
│   ├── DynamicModels
│   ├── Exceptions.py
│   ├── Helpers
│   ├── Models
│   ├── ToyModels
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__
├── docs
│   ├── 10_API
│   ├── 1_installation
│   ├── 2_getting_started
│   ├── 3_DynamicFBA
│   ├── 4_community_matrix
│   ├── 5_djoint
│   ├── 6_parallel_dfba
│   ├── 7_endpoint_fba
│   ├── 8_Advanced
│   ├── 9_faq
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── _build
│   ├── _static
│   ├── _templates
│   ├── conf.py
│   ├── index.rst
│   └── make.bat
├── pyproject.toml
├── sysbio_env.yml
```